# How do you make Python IDLE Shell look like a Character Cell Display?

Tags: python-2.7, python-idle

I am trying to use my IDLE Shell as a Character Cell display.

I have tried installing curses and unicurses but I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\#####\Documents\codestuffs\python\gameOfLife.py", line 3, in <module>
    import curses
  File "C:\Python27\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this particular error or use another module or even a way to make this work another way?

Answer (score 1):

You asked two separate questions.

I am not sure what you mean by "use my IDLE Shell as a Character Cell display". but it may be impossible. Shell displays the output of whatever statement you enter at '>>> ' or run from the editor, but it does not interpret ansi escape codes or other 'smart terminal' commands.  It simulates a 'dumb terminal'.

I know nothing about curses on Windows except that it is problematical.  Anything that does work will probably only work in Command Prompt.  Test your installation without involving Idle.  If you have problems, look for existing questions about curses on Windows.

Comment: This: http://i.imgur.com/riwG89g.png   has IDLE Shell. It's the window that gives you output from running code in the editor. Good point about that IDLE shell may not be the right tool for testing curses. Funny thing about curses, it doesn't just work on OSX either. I just need a character cell display library OR a way to move the cursor around the screen to draw a text-based GUI. That's it.

Comment: The cursor can be moved around a Text widget.  Notice that when you put the cursor on a previous statement and hit <Enter>, the Idle Shell code copies the code to the current >>> prompts *and* moves the cursor to the end of the copied statement.  But the same Idle shell code does not pass anything from user output to the Text widget.

Comment: There exists at least one module (tkvt100.py, requires ansi package on pypi.python.org) to make a Canvas widget act like a VT100 terminal.